# form.target not populating in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

The following code works fine in Chrome and IE10, but in Firefox I get an empty popupbox, while the page goes to a new tab. I want it in the popup.

HTML:

```
<form method='POST' target='' action='monthlystats.jsp' id=mform name=mform onsubmit="target_popup(this)">
<input type=hidden name=cards value=<%=cards%>>
<input type=hidden name=a value=<%=datefrom%>>
<input type=hidden name=b value=<%=dateto%>>
<input type=submit value='Monthly Statistics' >
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function target_popup(form) {
    var mw=window.open('', '_blanc', 'height=600px,width=1300px,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes');
    form.target = '_blanc';
}
```

The HTML code is delivered through an AJAX request, the javascript is in a general .js file.
At first I had 'MSTATS' as target name, but that did not even produce a popup in firefox until I changed it to '_blanc'. Chrome and IE work fine with either name.
A straight 'window.open(url, name, args)' does work okay, so I guess it's the 'target' that is causing the problem in firefox.

Comment: You should quote your attributes.

Comment: Yes, that seems to do the trick. Thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

Replace it twice:

> ```
> _blanc
> ```

```
_blank
```

Comment: Yes, of course. But in the end, it was not the problem. The quotes seem to have solved it.